# Activity being called many a times after timer expires

Tags: android, timer

I am launching an activity that calls itself and contains a timer and after the timer expires, I want to launch an activity but the problem is that the timer expires simultaneously in all the instances when the activity is called and as a result the second activity is called in all those instances. How to avoid this. The code is as follows-:

```
        public void onFinish() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Exam.this, ScoreCard.class);
                        intent.putExtra("scoreTillNow", scoreTillNow);
                        intent.putExtra("timeLeft", timeLeft);
                        intent.putExtra("reward", reward);
                        intent.putExtra("punishment", punishment);
                        intent.putExtra("totalTime", totalTime);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
```

Comment: where is the timer code?

Answer (score 0):

Decalare a public static boolean variable in any activity other than your timer activity and initialize it as false like :

```
public static boolean timerExpired = false;
```

Now check this variable when timer expires that if it is false call second activity and update variable as true. If variable is true, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) `singleTask` or `singleInstance` in your `Manifest` for your activity.
But please provide the code for your timer and more details